# Unable to use two monitors simultaneously (18.10)

Tags: drivers, nvidia, multiple-monitors, display

I am using 2 monitors:
First one which is my main monitor is connected via DVI to my videocard and the second one is connected via VGA to the integrated graphics.
After installing ubuntu (18.10) I had both monitors working together and properly, but after installing nvidia driver via software & update my **main** monitor has stopped working and now it's just black screen with blank signal. Changing drivers and manually installing them does not help. 
The main problem I need help with is to get monitors to work properly, or at least the main one.
I tried digging some solutions, but they couldn't solve my problem

Some outputs that I hope might be useful:

```
unicloud@unicloud-H81M-S1:~$ xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 1024 x 768, maximum 32767 x 32767
VGA1 connected primary 1024x768+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
300mm x 230mm
   1024x768      75.03*   70.07    60.00  
   832x624       74.55  
   800x600       72.19    75.00    60.32    56.25  
   640x480       75.00    72.81    66.67    59.94  
   720x400       70.08  
VIRTUAL1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis




unicloud@unicloud-H81M-S1:~$ lshw -c video
WARNING: you should run this program as super-user.
  *-display                 
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: GP106 [GeForce GTX 1060 6GB]
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: a1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=nvidia latency=0
       resources: irq:32 memory:f6000000-f6ffffff memory:e0000000-efffffff memory:f0000000-f1ffffff ioport:e000(size=128) memory:c0000-dffff
  *-display
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics     Controller
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 06
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: vga_controller bus_master cap_list
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: irq:30 memory:f7400000-f77fffff memory:d0000000-dfffffff ioport:f000(size=64)
```

Comment: You need to plug both monitors into your graphics card. Assuming it lacks VGA output, you will need to buy an adapter or another cable.

Comment: Unfortunately spending 15 bucks on an adapter that will not be useful to me for long is not an option. I am pretty sure there is a way to make them work properly at the same time considering that on first launch both monitors were working fine

Comment: I understand, but this is how Nvidia wants users to use their cards on Linux. They don't support multi-GPU very well unless you have a Quadro or you just use the open source drivers.

Answer (score 0):

If you have one output connected to your GPU and one to your iGPU, and your iGPU is enabled in the BIOS for multi-monitor display, you can try to link-up the provider output source with:

`xrandr --setprovideroutputsource 1 0`

Bear in mind, it is still highly experimental, so your results may vary. Had good results with Intel HD Graphics chips in the past.

Comment: Just tried your solution and it did not work, however after installing nvidia drivers manually my main monitor began to work, leaving the second monitor black-screened. Better than nothing!
I also tried getting connection status and I got this:

`unicloud@unicloud-H81M-S1:~$ grep . /sys/class/drm/*/status
/sys/class/drm/card0-VGA-1/status:connected
/sys/class/drm/card1-DP-1/status:disconnected
/sys/class/drm/card1-DVI-D-1/status:connected
/sys/class/drm/card1-DVI-D-2/status:disconnected
/sys/class/drm/card1-HDMI-A-1/status:disconnected
`

It can see the connection, but not use it.

Comment: Do you definitely have multi-monitor option for GPU and iGPU turned on in BIOS? Can you try `xrandr --listproviders`